# Can invoices be sent to and cc'd to multiple contacts?

Tags: email, invoice

I am trying to replicate an existing workflow within CiviCRM. I need to be able to send membership invoices to multiple recipients. An example is:

Subject: Membership invoice
To: accounts_payable@member.com, finance_director@member.com
cc: budget_holder@member.com, person_that_cares@member.com, secretariat@civicrm_user.com

Ideally this should be a single mail so that each recipient can see the others and whether they are "To" or "cc".

The current "email invoice" in contributions only seems to email the primary billing contact. Is it possible to do what I want?

Comment: Are you trying to send invoice one by one ? for multiple email ID ?

Comment: Yes, one invoice to multiple recipients.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an extension to do this called [altinvoice](https://github.com/MegaphoneJon/com.megaphonetech.altinvoice).  You can set relationship types to receive a copy of the invoice.  E.g. "When I invoice this organization, also send a copy to anyone with the relationship type of 'Billing Contact' or 'Site Coordinator'".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send one by one for multiple email ID - Try this

Use - Find Contribution screen and select the contribution which you want to send - then select email option which should allow you to send multiple email ID - in the same time

I guess this helps !!!

Comment: Good suggestion, but it doesn't quite work. If you select 'Print or email contribution invoices' you get the same email interface that only send to the primary billing contact. If you select 'Send email to contacts' you get the standard email interface with the primary billing invoice as the initial 'To' address, but no invoice attached.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to notify a number people that you've invoiced members - how about creating a report [showing these pending membership contributions] and then Emailing that report automatically (daily; w/ scheduled job) to all your recipients?

Comment: My goal here is to email one invoice to multiple recipients at a member organisation. We often have to send the invoice to their accounts payable department, but cc it to one or more people at that organisation that care about it being paid. About 30% of the invoices we send need to go to multiple recipients.

Comment: Ah that never occured to me - all our sites with corporate memberships typically have an approval/queue process where they pass on the invoice internally as it goes from one desk to another - from those that can approve it - essentially to those who pay for it - so we just invoice the 'primary contact' on record - to get that process started.

Answer (score 0):

We did some customisation so that the receipt would go out to other emails of the contributing contact - eg because they had a 'billing persons' email on the record of the donor - and they wanted receipts etc to go to both the Donor (primary email) and the billing person

Comment: Do you have an example of this posted publicly?  Thanks!

Comment: Not handy. Bundled up in a bunch of other customisations for them. Can't recall off hand if the 'billing persons email' was even a 'location type' field or a custom field. can look later if it would be helpful